# How to send values of ckeditor on my input ? Symfony 7

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

how to send values of my CKEditor on my input with $var->setArticle()
i have this on my form

```
            <div class="mb-6" id="editor">
            {# {{form_widget(formArticle.contenu)}} #}

        </div>
```

And i want try like this :

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $article->setContenu($_POST['contenu']);
        $entity->persist($article);
        $entity->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin');
    }
```

I use Symfony 7 and all packagist bundle are not compatible to my project...

i use CDN for import CKEDITOR

thx for your help !

all what i do is on my pictures

Comment: In formType just call CKEditorType and let doctrine save it. If you can't install ckeditor assets look here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCKEditorBundle/issues/253#issuecomment-1693278790